# function is 1-1 and onto

Tags: functions

Consider the relation 
$f(x,y) = (x+y, x-y)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers prove that $f$ is 1-1 and $f$ is onto $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Can you give me some hints how I should start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $f$ is one-to-one, we need to show that $f(a, b) = f(c, d)$ implies $(a, b) = (c, d)$.

So we have $a + b = c + d$ and $a - b = c - d$.  Add the two equations together to get $2a = 2c$, so that $a = c$.   It follows immediately that $b = d$, and so $f$ is one-to-one.

To prove $f$ is onto, let $(m, n) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.  By setting $x = \dfrac{m+n}{2}$ and $y = \dfrac{m - n}{2}$, we get

$$f(x, y) = (x + y, x - y) = \bigg(\dfrac{m+n}{2} + \dfrac{m-n}{2}, \dfrac{m+n}{2} - \dfrac{m - n}{2}\bigg) = (m, n) $$

Comment: is this an assumption that x = m+n/2?

Comment: @Lisa  What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

For $1-1$, let the image point be $(a,b)$. Work backwards to see that only one point goes there. For onto, show that some point comes there.

Answer (score 0):

These will follow directly from the definitions:

- For one-to-one, you need to show that if $$(x_1+y_1,x_1-y_1) = f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2,y_2) = (x_2 + y_2 , x_2 - y_2),$$ then $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$. You can do this by setting the coordinates equal to one another and then adding/subtracting the two equations.
- For onto, given $(a,b)$, you need to find $(x,y)$ so that $(x+y, x-y) = f(x,y) = (a,b)$. Again, you can do this from the equations obtained by setting the coordinates equal to one another. This is a system that you can solve in $x$ and $y$.

Does this make sense?